# Finding tight frustum around an AABB

Tags: matrix, 3d, projection-matrix, frustum, aabb

How do I build a tight-fitting view frustum around an AABB and a particular camera position?

Basically, I'm implementing frustum-traced shadows and reprojecting view samples to the point-light's view frustum. I want to optimize the light's projection by tightly bounding the view samples with a new frustum from light position. So basically, the new frustum will be a subset of the original one. I already have an AABB from the view samples (in light space), but I don't know how to turn it into a new frustum (= view/projection matrices).

Any help appreciated